# Device that transmits signal to computer

Tags: digital-logic, signal, ldr

How would I be able to send a notification or email/msg of some sort to my computer after an event has taken place from elsewhere. To be more specific, when a tripwire is tripped, (LDR/Laser beam) how would i be able to send a signal to my computer over wifi that it has been tripped?
Sorry if my question doesn't really make sense, I'm very new to electronics.

Comment: http://www.5mwd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/201502241.png?fit=500%2C646  lol

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 lol, yeah that but more simple and electronically hehe.

Comment: Are you designing such a device or are you shopping for such a device?

Comment: You need some kind of wifi transceiver, and if you're very new to electronics you don't want to be designing one of those yourself.

Comment: @brhans I thought that there would be some device already existent that could simply output a signal when turned on (through the circuit). I am ok with coding, and would probably be able to figure out how to work such a device.

Comment: Unfortunately, [shopping is off-topic here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ThisIsTheEndOfPineapples There is such a device, several in fact, but as brhans says, that's off topic for this site.

Comment: Ok all good, but would you be able to tell me what such a device is called? Like along the lines of a 'wireless signal transmitter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using an Arduino-style microcontroller platform. A microcontroller is a chip that you can program to do many things. Many of them have a built-in USB serial port, so you can send data from the chip and receive it on the computer. You can even write your own computer program to process the data, easily enough.

Note that you don't just want the chip, you want the whole board that's already set up and ready to program. The Arduino boards are examples of this, or the Blue Pill, or the Teensy.

You would connect your sensor to the microcontroller board and program the microcontroller to send data to the computer when the sensor trips. You would write another program for the computer, to play an alarm sound (or whatever you want it to do) when it receives data from the microcontroller.

If you want to send data across a large distance, you can find an add-on board (probably designed for an Arduino, but usable with other boards too) that will let you insert a SIM card and send data through the Internet using the cellphone network. That will be more complicated to set up.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer i was looking for, i thought of doing it using an arduino but wasn't sure if this was the simplest way.

Answer (score -1):

Numato Lab https://numato.com/ is a company that designs and manufactures various I/O boards for connection to computers. I once purchased the GP80001 model which connects to a computer by USB and was able work with arbitrary I/O bits using the Python language. Once you move those bits that represent activities going on outside the computer into the computer, you can work with this data programmatically and move this data to other computers by many available methods.